# SQL Sum Query issue

Tags: sql-server, sum

I'm new to SQL Server and struggling with this.

I have two select statements

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) AS "MONDAY" 
FROM 
    Transaction 
WHERE 
    Transaction_Date = '2015-12-21 00:00:00.000'

SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) AS "TUESDAY" 
FROM 
    Transaction 
WHERE 
    Transaction_Date = '2015-12-22 00:00:00.000'
```

Their result is 2,00,000 and 3,00,000 respectively

I want the output to be shown as two columns

(Column 1 + Monday) and (Column 2 = Tuesday) on SQL Server screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use `conditional aggregation` for that:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Date = '2015-12-21 00:00:00.000'  
           THEN Amount END) AS "MONDAY" ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Date = '2015-12-22 00:00:00.000' 
           THEN Amount END) AS "TUESDAY" 
FROM Transaction
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select datepart(dw, transactiondate),
    sum(amount) [sum]
from transaction
where transaction_date between '2015-12-22' and '2015-12-23'
group by datepart(dayofweek, transactiondate)
```

keep in mind, this is pseudo-code, I'm looking up the "dayofweek" attribute...

Lookup datepart here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: Nice approach but this will create multiple results versus a single row with multiple columns...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use MSSQL Pivot function to transform rows into columns.
Check this other question. Maybe this can help you:
[Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)